# Blank Domain Modelling Page in Typo3 Extension Builder

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

After installing the Extension Builder in Typo3 6.1 I only get a blank screen if I go to "Domain Modelling" page.

I tried to logout and login again as admin without success.

I cleared all caches with no success.

I don't see any fatals in my php error log?

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you try cleaning typo3temp/ directory completely? Also the webservers error log should at least show some errors, since a white page can occour, when code executions failed due to a PHP error.

Comment: Also, try disabling all Debug settings in typo3conf/Additionalconf.php - probably not that, but I get errors at saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the Firefox Console I found lots of Javascript Errors. Seems to be related with this issue: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/48457

Using Chrome Browser instead solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is true but sad. There are TYPO3-functions that are optimized for Firefox (such as the RTE) and there are TYPO3-functions that are optimized for Chrome (such as this Extension Builder). Now I end up having **two** browsers running all the time :(